# Quicksort implementation optimization

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, optimization, quicksort

So I've implemented a version for quick sort but I'm not sure if I did it in an optimal way. The elements in the vector that I am sorting are 3D points. You will notice that when splitting the array it says "if(level == 1), if(level == 2), etc" This is because depending on when I'm calling quicksort, either the x, y, or z coordinate of the points is the basis of the sorting.

My code is below. I've tested my algorithm and it seems to be sorting the points correctly, however I feel like I may have a lot of overhead or something because it doesn't run as fast as I hoped it would run, especially since I have to call this sort function many times to sort arrays as large as 500,000 elements.

Is there anything I can do to improve/clean up/speed up my sort algorithm?

```
std::vector<Point> SortPoints(std::vector<Point> points, int level)
{
    if(points.size() <= 1) return points;
    std::vector<Point> s1, s2;
    size_t index = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)*(points.size()-1);
    Point pivot = points[index];
    points.erase(points.begin() + index);
    size_t size = points.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(level == 1)
        {
            if(points[i].pos.x <= pivot.pos.x) s1.push_back(points[i]);
            else s2.push_back(photons[i]);
        } else if(level == 2)
        {
            if(points[i].pos.y <= pivot.pos.y) s1.push_back(points[i]);
            else s2.push_back(photons[i]);
        } else if(level == 3)
        {
            if(points[i].pos.z <= pivot.pos.z) s1.push_back(points[i]);
            else s2.push_back(photons[i]);
        }
    }
    if(s1.size() == 0) return Concatenate(s1, pivot, s2); 
    else if(s2.size() == 0) return Concatenate(s1, pivot, s2);
    else return Concatenate(SortPoints(s1, level), pivot, SortPoints(s2, level)); 
}

std::vector<Point> Concatenate(std::vector<Point> s1, 
                                       Point p, std::vector<Point> s2)
{  
    std::vector<Point> result;
    result.reserve(s1.size()+s2.size()+1);
    result.insert(result.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end());
    result.push_back(p);
    result.insert(result.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you are not using `std::sort`? perhaps you can compare against it to check performance.

Comment: One reason to use your own sort is that you may have an idea about the distribution of your data, which can aid in the selection of a better pivot than random selection

Comment: Note that there is a [special stackexchange only for codereviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you're creating copies when you're partitioning. There's *a lot* of memory allocation and copying going on behind the scenes.

If you want it faster you need to sort in place (and don't pass huge vectors by value).

Unless this is an exercise to implement quicksort you should use `std::sort` with custom comparison functions.

Comment: But if I use std::sort, how would I be able to tell it which coordinate point to use to sort? Because right now I pass in an int 'level', and depending on that I sort based on x, y or z.

Comment: @user1855952 You can pass level in the comparison functor.

Comment: @user1855952: There are several ways: you could use a "functor" (an object with a function call operator) which has the "level" as a member, or simply write one function per coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

So here are a few observations:

- You should, as others have noted, consider using the std implementation as a benchmark.
- You could pre-reserve the vectors you're sorting into, rather than have them continually grow and re-allocate.
- It might be better to skip the pivot in the loop, rather than erase it from the vector, as the latter might require a lot of copying of data.
- You could not bother with copying data into new vectors and concatenating them, and instead sort in place.
- You could perhaps pick a better pivot than doing so at random (especially if your data is pre-sorted).
- You could alter the implementation of your Point to allow indexing xyz instead of having to use an if()

Essentially, this seems like quite a naive implementation, and you'll probably have to do quite a bit of work, and utilise specialist knowledge of your own data, in order to beat the pre-supplied version.